# Laplacian of a cross product

Tags: vector-analysis, laplacian, cross-product

I'm trying to work out different product rules for the Laplacian and I've gotten stuck on the Laplacian of a cross product.

Suppose $A = A_i\mathbf{\hat{e}}_i$ and $B = B_i\mathbf{\hat{e}}_i$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then

\begin{align}
\Delta\left(A\times B\right)
&= \epsilon_{ijk}\Delta\left(A_jB_k\right)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_i \\ 
&= \epsilon_{ijk}\left[A_j\Delta B_k + 2\partial_mA_j\partial_mB_k + B_k\Delta A_j\right]\mathbf{\hat{e}}_i \\
&= A\times\left(\Delta B\right) + 2\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_mA_j\partial_mB_k\mathbf{\hat{e}}_i + \left(\Delta A\right)\times B
\end{align}

I can't identify the second term on the last line with anything meaningful in terms of standard vector calculus operations.

Comment: Not really, my problem is that I can't identify the term $\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_mA_j\partial_mB_k$ with anything more familiar from vector calculus.

Comment: Well, the answer provided there actually tells you what those mixed terms are. So writing them out should give you the desired formula.

Comment: The result of adding up all the terms is simply just to arrive back at $\epsilon{ijk}\partial_mA_j\partial_mB_k$. My question is whether or not this can be written in terms of more familiar vector calculus operations.  It feels somewhat odd, that the two of the three terms can be written neatly in terms of "standard" vector calculus operators (namely the laplacian and the cross product) but the third term can't.

Answer (score 0):

We use the formula
\begin{equation}\tag{1}                                                            
\Delta(fg) = f\Delta g + 2\nabla f \cdot \nabla g + g\Delta f                   
\end{equation}
in the deriving an expression for $\vec{X}=\Delta(\vec{A} \times \vec{B})$.
Now,
\begin{equation}\tag{2}                                                            
\vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \hat{e}_x(A_yB_z - A_zB_y) + \hat{e}_y(A_zB_x -        
A_xB_z) + \hat{e}_z(A_xB_y - A_yB_x)                                            
\end{equation}
so that, using the first equation,
\begin{eqnarray}                                                                
X_x &=& (A_y\Delta B_z - A_z\Delta B_x) + 2(\nabla A_y \cdot \nabla B_z -          
 \nabla A_z\cdot\nabla B_y) + (B_z\Delta A_y - B_y\Delta A_z) \nonumber \\         
X_y &=& (A_z\Delta B_x - A_x\Delta B_z) + 2(\nabla A_z \cdot \nabla B_x -          
 \nabla A_x\cdot\nabla B_z) + (B_x\Delta A_z - B_z\Delta A_x) \nonumber \\         
X_y &=& (A_x\Delta B_y - A_y\Delta B_x) + 2(\nabla A_x \cdot \nabla B_y -          
 \nabla A_y\cdot\nabla B_x) + (B_y\Delta A_x - B_x\Delta A_y) \nonumber         
\end{eqnarray}
The manipulations are a little tedious but you can use "cyclic permutations" trick for getting successive terms of a cross product. The first terms on the right hand side of the three equations are just the components of $\vec{A} \times \Delta\vec{B}$. Likewise, the third terms of are the components of $\vec{B} \times \Delta\vec{A}$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}\tag{3}                                                           
\vec{X} = \vec{A}\times\Delta\vec{B} + \vec{Y} + \vec{B}\times\Delta\vec{A}        
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\tag{4}                                                              
\frac{\vec{Y}}{2}=\hat{e}_x(\nabla A_y \cdot \nabla B_z - \nabla A_z\cdot\nabla B_y)        
+ \hat{e}_y(\nabla A_z \cdot \nabla B_x - \nabla A_x\cdot\nabla B_z)           
+ \hat{e}_z(\nabla A_x \cdot \nabla B_y - \nabla A_y\cdot\nabla B_x)           
\end{equation}
The term $\partial_m A_j \partial_m B_k$ is indeed a dot product of gradient of $A_j$ and the gradient of $B_k$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ ensures that $j \ne k$. Unless I have made a mistake in the derivation the middle term in your equation is just the vector $\vec{Y}$ defined in equation (4).

Comment: I agree, my question is just whether your $\vec{Y}$ vector can be written in terms of more familiar vector calculus operations. It feels somewhat odd, that the two of the three terms can be written more neatly.